# does anyone know how to list the empid and the name of all supervisors if supervisors are in employee table too?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table that contains `empid`, `name`, `salary`, `hiredate`, `position` and `supervisor` (which includes `empid`, not the name). How do I list the empid and name of all supervisors?

The output has to have to columns `supervisor` (and a list of their empid) and their names. This is the `create` statement used to create the `Employee` table:

```
/* Create table Employee */
IF OBJECT_ID('Employee', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE Employee
GO
CREATE TABLE Employee (
emp_id NCHAR(5), 
name NVARCHAR(20), 
position NVARCHAR(20),
hire_date DATETIME,
salary MONEY, 
bcode NCHAR(3),
supervisor NCHAR(5)
)
```

I have tried a variety of statements using having statement and count but they don't seem to work.

```
select emp_id, name from employee where position='manager';
```

I tried this but it doesn't work. Anyone smart that knows how to do it?

Comment: Do a self join with emp table.

Comment: I have a table that contains empid, name, salary, hiredate, positionand supervisor (which includes empid not the name) how do i list the empid and name of all supervisors ? the output has to have to columns supervisor( and a list of their emid) and their names

Answer (score 2):

You will have to join the table back on itself:

```
select a.name, a.position, a.hiredate, a.salary, a.supervisorid, 
isnull(b.name, '') as SupervisorName 
from EmployeeTable a 
left join EmployeeTable b 
on a.SupservisorID=b.ID
```

The left join will make sure that the employees who do not have supervisors are returned, and `isnull(b.name, '<NONE>')` can be used if you would like to have something other than `NULL` as a value in those cases.

Comment: I dont think this is the statement that i need. I need to get a list of employee id and name for the supervisors . I have a table with all employees but supervisors are listed in it too so i need to run a statement taht will lust only supervisors empid and their names. thats the create statement i have for this table /* Create table Employee */
IF OBJECT_ID('Employee', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE Employee
GO
CREATE TABLE Employee (
emp_id NCHAR(5), 
name NVARCHAR(20), 
position NVARCHAR(20),
hire_date DATETIME,
salary MONEY, 
bcode NCHAR(3),
supervisor NCHAR(5)
)

Comment: /* populate table Employee */
INSERT INTO Employee (emp_id, name, position, hire_date, salary, bcode, supervisor)
SELECT 'E1001','Kennedy','Director','1984/01/16',50000,'B01',Null
UNION ALL
SELECT 'E1045','Smith','Salesman','1994/05/12',18000,'B04','E3691'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'E1271','Stewart','Clerk','1989/04/30',16000,'B03','E3255'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'E1534','Bell','Manager','1995/11/28',20000,'B01','E3876'

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.empid  ,ISNULL(b.name, 'No supervisor') SupervisorName 
FROM employee e LEFT JOIN  employee b
ON e.supervisorid = b.empid
```

Inner join will leave out the people who do not have a supervisor , Use left join to get all the employees

Comment: you have an extra alias and i think you are confusing them. it should be e instead of a in the SELECT, and the ON should be reversed: e.supervisorid = b.empid

Comment: @FilipeSilva well spotted :)

Comment: but all i need is emp id and name for supervisor that is in the employee table all together with all employees. its one table that includes employeeid, name, salary, position and their supervisor , all i need to list is supervisor's emp id and name

Comment: @user3067155 then just select the empid and and the name from aliased table I have update my answer please have a look and the sample data you have provided, none of the employees have a supervisor whos id is in this provided data :)

Comment: I have a table that contains empid, name, salary, hiredate, positionand supervisor (which includes empid not the name) how do i list the empid and name of all supervisors ? the output has to have to columns supervisor( and a list of their emid) and their names

Answer (score 0):

If you want supervisors only, you just need to select rows whose `emp_id` values are found in the `supervisor` column:

```
SELECT
  SupervisorID   = emp_id,
  SupervisorName = name
FROM dbo.Employee
WHERE emp_id IN (SELECT supervisor FROM dbo.Employee)
;
```